# find pods item where relationship to other pod is not set

Tags: sql, pods-framework

I need to fix the effect of an error that left empty a relationship field that should have been autofilled.

To fix this I need to find all pods item that has the relationship not set, but I don't know how to do it.

I tried with `'where' => 'source.id = ""'` in a `find()` but with no luck.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is:

`source.id IS NULL`

This will match items that have no source set at all.